# XFA missing filled fields?

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, xfa, acrofields

I am using pdfbox-1.8.12 to read content from PDF to get XFA.
I have been able to get XFA for most of the files successfully without missing out on any field values.

The trouble is with some files like [error.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByD-BQCPkgGMemNtNkpDaGtUbUk/view?usp=sharing). I have many of the fields having no values like CIN, but when I open the file in any PDF Viewer, foxit or Acrobat it shows that field.

```
    public static byte[] getParsableXFAForm(File file) {
    if (file == null)
        return null;
    PDDocument doc;
    PDDocumentCatalog catalog;
    PDAcroForm acroForm;
    PDXFA xfa;
    try {
        doc = PDDocument.load(file);
        catalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
        acroForm = catalog.getAcroForm();
        xfa = acroForm.getXFA();
        byte[] xfaBytes = xfa.getBytes();
        doc.close();
        return xfaBytes;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle IOException
        // happens when the file is corrupt.
        System.out.println("IOException");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then the byte[] is converted to String.

[This](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByD-BQCPkgGMOWMzZ0J2ODNsZTA) is the xfa for this file and if you search in this for 'U72300DL1996PLC075672', it would be missing.

This is a [normal](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByD-BQCPkgGMQzJIb1lXX3NCSFU) file, that gives all fields.

Any Ideas? I have tried everything, but my guess is that since readers can see that value, I should be able to as well.

EDIT : 
You will have to download the files, you might not be able to view them in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple entries of XFA content within the form representing the different states the form had prior to applying the different signatures. As you are using

`PDDocument.load(file)`

the PDF is parsed sequentially and the most current XFA content is not picked up. If you change that to

`PDDocument.loadNonSeq(file,null)`

the Xref information is used and the most current XFA is extracted containing the information you are looking for.

Note that for PDFBox 1.8.x one should always use `PDDocument.loadNonSeq` in order to parse the PDF in line with the specification i.e. by following the Xref information. `PDDocument.load` should **only** be used to handle files with (Xref related) parsing errors where a sequential parsing can be a fall back.

For PDFBox 2.x `PDDocument.load` parses following the Xref i.e. like `PDDocument.loadNonSeq' in 1.8 and sequential parsing is done behind the scenes in case there are errors.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. I had tried every possible thing I could, I thought it was the error of parsing. I was instead saving the file again and then parsing it. Thanks again!! Cheers!!